# setViewName changed

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

In the latest version of cocos2d-x, it seems like `eglView->setViewName("Hello World")` doesn't work anymore. What was it changed to?

i.e. in the HelloCpp project in main.cpp:

```
// create the opengl view
CCEGLView* eglView = CCEGLView::sharedOpenGLView();

// set the window name
eglView->setViewName("Hello World");
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Windows you can set name using Window Handle (HWND).

```
HWND handle = eglView->getHWnd();
SetWindowText(handle, "MY_GAME_TITLE");
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

*eglView->setViewName* and *getViewName* are removed from the latest cocos2d-x

I know without that we can not change the windows title

But If you want you can edit the CCEGLView code and try to set it directly

```
CCEGLView* eglView = CCEGLView::sharedOpenGLView();
strcpy(eglView->m_szViewName, "Test");
```

Manipulate the *cocos2d::CCEGLViewProtocol::m_szViewName* protected member accordingly...

This is not the best way to do it ... Or else wait till they add it again

Give it a try ...

Comment: Well, why did they remove it in the first place, if they are going to "add it again" anyway?

Comment: @Ben : I am not sure they are going to add it ...I said wait till they add it again because i have seen request while going through bugs of cocos2d-x ...so they might or they might not